# Entity Framework with multiple result set from stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, multiple-resultsets

Is there any kind of limitation with entity framework for number of result set accepted that is returned by stored procedure?
I tried to get 3 result sets from stored procedure in enitity framework but everytime I get error of

> The type parameter 'EfDesignerSprocMultiSets.GetProductStatus_Result'
>   in ExecuteFunction is incompatible with the type
>   'StoreDBModel.Product_SprocResult' returned by the function.

I tried to implement code from this [website](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/675933/Returning-Multiple-Result-Sets-from-an-Entity-Fram). It works perfect but when I try to add one more result set I get above error.

Comment: It this database-first?